# Как тестировать методы использующие суперглобальные массивы

Tags: php, phpunit

Разбираюсь с PHPUnit, вроде понял, как пишутся тесты для методов с параметрами, но возник вопрос, как тестировать методы без параметров, внутри которых информация берётся из `$_POST`?

Comment: Можно подменить содержимое $_POST перед вызовом тестируемого метода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-хорошему, ваши методы не должны взаимодействовать напрямую с суперглобальными массивами (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` и прочими). Тому есть целый ряд причин:

1. Ваш код становится более запутанным и не очевидным. Если значение суперглобального массива изменится где-то в коде, то вам предстоит "увлекательный" сеанс отладки.
2. Тестирование кода, использующего глобальные переменные представляет определенные трудности и требует дополнительной возни с установкой правильного контекста вызова тестируемого метода.
3. Используя массивы `$_GET` и `$_POST` вы жестко привязываетесь к определенному формату запросов (HTTP запросы) и вынуждены будете переписать много кода, если внешний API вашего приложения изменится, скажем, на SOAP.

---

Тем не менее, код использующий суперглобальные переменные все-таки можно тестировать. Для этого PHPUnit оставляет вам "лазейку": все значения суперглобальных массивов копируются перед запуском пакета тестов и восстанавливаются по окончанию каждого тестового метода. Вот что об этом написано в [документации PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html):

> By default, PHPUnit runs your tests in a way where changes to global and super-global variables (`$GLOBALS`, `$_ENV`, `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SERVER`, `$_FILES`, `$_REQUEST`) do not affect other tests. Optionally, this isolation can be extended to static attributes of classes.

Таким образом, вы можете задать необходимые значения полей массива `$_POST` в каждом из тестовых методов не думая о последствиях. Например так:

```
class Controller
{
    public function loadUser()
    {
        $user = new \stdClass();
        $user->id = (int)$_POST['user_id'];

        return $user;
    }
}

class ControllerTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testUserLoading()
    {
        $_POST['user_id'] = 123;

        $controller = new Controller();
        $user = $controller->loadUser();

        $this->assertEquals(123, $user->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, постараюсь, как только освободиться время переписать методы использующие $_POST и т.д